# Codeigniter shows 404 error on Windows server 2012

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have installed codeigniter on a windows server 2012. However, the application which works fine on my local wamp server shows CI 404 page on the server. Even the constructor of default controller doesn't get initialized.
This is the htaccess code of my application.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also have mod_rewrite enabled on the server.

Comment: Have you changed the configuration to have the correct URL as the base_url?

Comment: Yes I have changed the base_url to the correct URL.

Comment: Is `uri_protocol` set to `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: yes it is set to REQUEST_URI

Comment: Are the requests in showing in the apache access logs?

Comment: Yes they are showing up. The requests are sent correctly, however the codeigniter routes are not working properly.